# How would one compare Cache Allocating Technology against MIT's Dynamically Allocated Way Guard for prevention of the Spectre side-channel Attack?

Tags: meltdown, spectre, side-channel, cpu, intel

Upon research, I'm finding it difficult to identify a way to compare each solution. Is it correct in saying both solutions are software based? Therefore, could I compare overall PC perfomance with each software implementation?

Comment: This is already discussed in the [paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/vlk/dawg-micro18.pdf) in Section II.C.2.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for that. Although the paper compares the two prevention strategies in-depth, I was wondering if there are any methods I could use to gather data on the result of using both software patches (CAT and DAWG). A large chunk of the paper focuses on minimal OS performance changes. If both preventions are software-based, would I be right in saying I could run a benchmark test on my system with the software and one without then compare the data? This is where I feel I'm getting confused haha! :)

Comment: Essentially, what is the basis for my comparison? I have the option to write code.

Comment: Many changes in the hardware are required to implement DAWG, in addition to changes in the operating system. So you can only run DAWG in a simulator, not on a real system. For performance comparison with CAT, the authors have also implemented CAT in their simulator as discussed in Section VI.A.